# Google NDB: Best way to read child entities from an entity, repeated property vs regular query?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Let's say i have this really simple parent/child relatiosnship **(any `Answer` class instances always has a `Question` parent)**:

```
class Answer(ndb.Model):
    content = ndb.StringProperty()
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty()

    def to_message():
        """Returns a protoRPC message object of the answer"""


class Question(ndb.Model):
    content = ndb.StringProperty()
    answers = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated = True, kind = 'Answer')

    def to_message(self):
        """Returns a protoRPC message object of the question"""
```

The two `to message` methods are simply used to return a protoRPC object.
The question is: in my `to_message` method, in the `Question` class, if i want to fetch all child `Answer` instances, retrieve them, and use their own `to_message` method to make them into a nice rpc Message, is it better to:

- Iterate over the `anwers` repeated KeyProperty list
- Do a query using a filter on the "parent" property, and iterate over the list it outputs

In terms of NDB access, the first method seems to be the best, but since we're going to go over the free limit anyway, i'm more wondering if the datastore is not more efficient at fetching stuff than i am, iterating over that list.

**Edit: The original question has actually a very simple and obvious answer: the first way. 
The real question would be, in case I have to filter out some `Answer` entities based on their attributes (for instance `timestamp`): is it better to query using a filter, or iterate over the list and use a condition to gather only the "interesting" entities?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that schema you don't have to query anything because you already have the keys of each answer as a list of keys in `question_entity.answers`

So you only have to fetch the answers using that keys. Is better if you get all the answers in only one operation.

```
list_of_answers = ndb.get_multi(question_entity.answers)
```

(More info at [NDB Entities and Keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities?hl=es#multiple))

On the other hand, if you model that relationship with a `KeyProperty` in `Answer`:

```
class Answer(ndb.Model):
    question = ndb.KeyProperty(Question)
    content = ndb.StringProperty()
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty()

def to_message():
    """Returns a protoRPC message object of the answer"""
```

or with ancestors:

```
answer = Answer(parent=question_entity.key)
```

In these cases you should use a normal query for retrieve the answers:

```
answers = Answer.query(Answer.question == question_entity.key)
```

or an ancestor query:

```
answers = Answer.query(ancestor = question_entity.key)
```

respectively.

This means two jobs: Query the index **plus** fetching the datastore. In conclusion, in this case the first approach is cheaper for retrieving datastore data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I think my current question is kind of stupid. The real question would be: imagine I have a list of keys, and I want to get a list of entities filtered out by some condition on one of their attribute (timestamp value for instance). Is it more efficient to query, or to iterate over the list?

Comment: In that case, with your schema, is not feasible to query. You should iterate over all the entities, and filtering with python code. The other option is using the `KeyProperty(Question)` into `Answer` like the example above. In this case you can filter Answers by Question and also by other attributes in the same query. The last option is cheaper (and faster) because you only retrieves the Answers you need.

Comment: A third (or fourth if you count ancestors) option is using a [Structured Property](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured). Like everything it has pros and cons.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible to query? If it set my parent property for any Answer entity, I should be able to query, shouldn't I? (Using the "ancestor" filter)

Comment: That's what I said. If you set a parent you can do an ancestor query. If you don't set a parent, you must iterate over the entities list.

Comment: Note that using a repeated property in the question entity to track the answers (the first approach) is inherently limited by the entity max size of 1 MB. No question would likely have that many answers that it would hit the limit, but I'm just putting it out here as a consideration for others who may want to model their data similarly but for another scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ndb.get_multi` on the list of keys to fetch the Answers, and then iterating to call their to_message methods will be the most efficient.

Comment: Could oyu be more specific in regards to the efficiency of your method?